# Bluemix: MQA : how to make phone shake harder in android to report bug and feedback

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am trying to integrate Bluemix MQA with my mobile app. I am using the `MQA-Android-2.7.4.arr` file in my project. I have one query related to phone-shake as below.

How do I make the phone shake harder in Android to report a bug as slight shaking is also popping up the screen multiple times?

Comment: what've you tried? and explain a bit on this part - *how to make phone shake harder in android to report a bug as slight shaking is also popping up the screen multiple times*

Comment: I think what they mean is how can they adjust the shake force needed to trigger the bug report. In other words, allowing a 'weak' shake to go unnoticed, and how to change that threshold.

Comment: yes you are right Dave. my question is that can we change the threshold from our end? or it is totally depends on MQA SDK .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android devices have different accelerometers and the same algorithm appears to have different effects on each. I’m creating a request for enhancement to add a shake threshold slider for the shake gesture.

Comment: So it seems that we can not edit the shake gesture from our end? it's totally depends on the MQA sdk .