# Bluemix - MQA : Stop notification that keeps on popping up on screen in android

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am trying to integrate Bluemix MQA with my mobile app. I am using `MQA-Android-2.7.4.arr` file in my project. I have one query related to notification popups in android as below.

How do you stop notifications that keep popping up on the screen in Android?

Comment: Can you clarify what the notification popup you are referring to? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057784/bluemix-mqa-how-to-make-phone-shake-harder-in-andriod-to-report-bug-and-feedb

Comment: Here is the image  <http://i.stack.imgur.com/jfR6Q.png>    which displays the notification which i dont want in my Phone. because in IOS i am not getting any notification when the MQA is initialized but in android i am getting this notification whenever I lunch my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup notification cannot be suppressed in QA (pre-production) mode but will not be displayed in Market (production) mode.

Comment: but my concern is that in production mode shaking functionality is disabled. so can we enable shaking functionality in production mode?

Comment: Not at this time. It's on our roadmap for 2Q though.